# Using value inside a variable without expanding

Tags: bash, sed, sh

I am trying to find and replace a specific text content using the sed command and to run it via a shell script.

Below is the sample script that I am using:

```
fp=/asd/filename.txt

fd="sed -i -E 's ($2).* $2:$3 g' ${fp}"
eval $fd
```

and executing the same by passing the arguments:

```
./test.sh update asd asdfgh
```

But if the argument string contains `$` , it breaks the commands and it is replacing with wrong values, like

```
./test.sh update asd $apr1$HnIF6bOt$9m3NzAwr.aG1Yp.t.bpIS1.
```

How can I make sure that the values inside the variables are not expanded because of the `$`?

### Updated

sh file test.sh

```
set -xv

fp="/asd/filename.txt"

sed -iE "s/(${2//'$'/'\$'}).*/${2//'$'/'\$'}:${3//'$'/'\$'}/g" "$fp"
```

text file filename.txt

```
hello:world
```

Outputs

1)
    ./test.sh update hello WORLD

```
sed -iE "s/(${2//'$'/'\$'}).*/${2//'$'/'\$'}:${3//'$'/'\$'}/g" "$fp"
++ sed -iE 's/(hello).*/hello:WORLD/g' /asd/filename.txt
```

2)
    ./test.sh update hello '$apr1$hosgaxyv$D0KXp5dCyZ2BUYCS9BmHu1'

```
sed -iE "s/(${2//'$'/'\$'}).*/${2//'$'/'\$'}:${3//'$'/'\$'}/g" "$fp"
++ sed -iE 's/(hello).*/hello:'\''$'\''apr1'\''$'\''hosgaxyv'\''$'\''D0KXp5dCyZ2BUYCS9BmHu1/g' /asd/filename.txt
```

In both the case , its not replacing the content

Comment: Why do you need `eval` at all?

Comment: @BenjaminW. I thought that is the way to execute the dynamic commands . Havent used scripting till now. And i don't even know the basics of it. So i am all ears

Comment: What does `filename.txt` look like, and why isn't it just a file of function definitions that you can source, so that you can call the appropriate function instead of using `eval`?

Comment: @chepner it is  the htpassword file wiht usernames and encrypted passwords

Comment: Sorry, I misread the assignment; I thought you were trying to execute the *result* of `sed` as a command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `eval` here at all:

```
fp=/asd/filename.txt
sed -i -E "s/(${2//'$'/'\$'}).*/\1:${3//'$'/'\$'}/g" "$fp"
```

- The whole sed command is in double quotes so variables can expand.
- I've replaced the blank as the `s` separator with `/` (doesn't really matter in the example).
- I've used `\1` to reference the first capture group instead of repeating the variable in the substitution.
- Most importantly, I've used `${2//'$'/'\$'}` instead of `$2` (and similar for `$3`). This escapes every `$` sign as `\$`; this is required because of the double quoting, or the `$` get eaten by the shell before sed gets to see them.

When you call your script, you must escape any `$` in the input, or the shell tries to expand them as variable names:

```
./test.sh update asd '$apr1$HnIF6bOt$9m3NzAwr.aG1Yp.t.bpIS1.'
```

Comment: but when i trigger the same with $apr1$HnIF6bOt$9m3NzAwr.aG1Yp.t.bpIS1. as the 3rd argument, its replacing it with the string after the last '$'.. ie 'm3NzAwr.aG1Yp.t.bpIS1'

Comment: i was using blank as the s separator because my string can have '/' in the value.

Comment: @Andromeda You also have to quote `$` when calling your command, I've added a usage example.

Comment: its not working for me... i even tried with inputs that doesnt have any $.. Its not replacing the content

Comment: @Andromeda Are you on macOS, by chance?

Comment: no..i have windows machine Connected to my linux server via ssh.

Comment: @Andromeda Try adding `set -vx` to your script to see what exactly gets run.

Comment: @Andromeda Use `-i -E` instead of `-iE`, I had that wrong at first in my answer.

Comment: yes. even i missed that when i copy pasted it.
Now its replacing the entires. But with some extra quotes for every $
instead of $apr1$HnIF6bOt$9m3NzAwr.aG1Yp.t.bpIS1 it replaces with '$'apr1'$'HnIF6bOt'$'9m3NzAwr.aG1Yp.t.bpIS1

Comment: not only that ..if my string contains '/', its not there in the output. (the reason why i was using blank as seperator for s

Comment: removed the single quotes and it is working as expected

    sed -i -E "s (${2//$/\$}).* \1:${3//$/\$} g" "$fp"

Answer (score 0):

Put the command-line arguments that are filenames in single quotes:

```
./test.sh update 'asd' '$apr1$HnIF6bOt$9m3NzAwr.aG1Yp.t.bpIS1'
```

Comment: The stupid eval` probably prevents this from working, so it's not sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

must protect all the script arguments with quotes if having space and special shell char, and escape it if it's a dollar `$`, and `-Ei` instead of -iE even better drop it first for test, may add it later if being really sure
I admit i won't understant your regex so let's just get in the gist of solution, no need eval;

```
fp=/asd/filename.txt

sed -Ei "s/($2).*/$2:$3/g" $fp

./test.sh update asd '\$apr1\$HnIF6bOt\$9m3NzAwr.aG1Yp.t.bpIS1.'
```